# Visual Studio 2015 C#: Autocomplete adds fully qualified name

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, visual-studio-lightbulbs

Is there a way to turn this off?  It messes with my readability, plus VS automatically adds a "This code can be simplified" lightbulb to simplify the name anyway - which is both funny and insulting at the same time.

Here's an example.  In one file

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1.SubNamespace
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void aFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("aFunc called.");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in another

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication1.SubNamespace;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class AnotherClass
    {
        SomeClass instance;
        List<SomeClass> aList;

        public AnotherClass()
        {
            instance = new SubNamespace.SomeClass();
            aList = new List<SubNamespace.SomeClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force VS2015 to *not* use fully qualified names when auto-completing?  I've tried researching this and am coming up empty, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate this issue in VS 2015 or VS 2017. Is this still an issue for you? When I create a similar Class with a SubNamespace, Intellisense suggests "SomeClass" and not "SubNamespace.SomeClass" (in 2015 & 2017).

Comment: This does not happen for me either. Do you have any extensions that could be doing this? Sounds like a Resharper option.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well in VS2019, I think it might have something to do with code auto formatting preferences.